# Problemas con async await en el contructor de una clase typescrip vuex y axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, axios, vuex

Estoy programando el cliente de una api con typescript. Utilizo axios y vuex,

este es el código

```
import { CredentialsInterface } from '../store/Interfaces/auth';
import Store from '@/store/index';
import axios from 'axios';


class AuthenticateClient {
    http: any;
    credentials: CredentialsInterface;
    constructor() {
        this.credentials = Store.getters.credentials;
        console.log(this.credentials);

        this.http = axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://api.dashboarda.proyect',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization:
                    this.credentials.tokenType + ' ' + this.credentials.token
            }
        });
    }

    async get(endPoint: string, data: any) {
        console.log(this.http);
        try {
            return await this.http.get(endPoint);
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response.status == 401) {
                Store.commit('deleteSession');
            }
        }
    }

    async post(endPoint: string, data: any) {
        try {
            return await this.http.post(endPoint, data);
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response.status == 401) {
                Store.commit('deleteSession');
            }
        }
    }
}

export default new AuthenticateClient();
```

El problema que tienes que, no inicializa el **token** y el **token_type**

Estas son las cabeceras con las que sale la peticion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en consola si esta incializadas las credenciales 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que es un problema de sincronización porque cuando se ejecuta la función aun no están cargadas las variables de vuex.

Sin embargo no puedo volver una promesa al constructor o no conozco la forma de hacer esto.

Comment: Encontre mi error leyendo la pregunta, en la interfaz tienen nombres diferentes que en el store. No se porque el store no me da un error al recibir data diferente a la interfaz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate que cuando se consologea las credenciales en:

```js
    console.log(this.credentials);
```

Se esta mostrando:

```js
    {access_token: 'token', token_type: 'Bearer', ...}
```

Al parecer al traer las keys del objecto donde estan las credenciales pasa el **camelcase** al **underscore** o se deben estar llamando diferentes en el Store.

En vez de hacer

```js
    this.credentials.tokenType + ' ' + this.credentials.token
```

Proba con esto:

```js
    this.credentials.token_type + ' ' + this.credentials.access_token
```

Espero que te ayude!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta ya había dado con el error de cambio de nombre. Lo que no entiendo es porque no me tiro ni un error si al momento de guardar las credenciales no cumplían con la interfaz.